# Generic Builder Pattern class using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, builder-pattern

It would be great to make a implementation of the builder pattern with generics. In theory it would be possible to use reflection to make the following possible:

```
    MyClass myClass = GenericBuilder<MyClass>.aObject()
            .withThisProperty("foo")
            .withThatProperty(4)
            .build();
```

I already made the following code:

```
    public class CursistBuilder {
        private Cursist cursist = null;

        private CursistBuilder() {
            cursist = new Cursist("username not set", "email not set");
        }

        public static CursistBuilder aCursist() {
            return new CursistBuilder();
        }

        public CursistBuilder withNaam(String name) {
            cursist.setGebruikersnaam(name);
            return this;
        }

        public CursistBuilder withEmail(String email) {
            cursist.setEmail(email);
            return this;
        }

        public Cursist build() {
            return cursist;
        }
    }
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not proper builder pattern, as object is not created in `create` function, but you could use it as reference for improvement

```
public static class Builder<T> {
        public final T instance;

        public Builder(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException,
                IllegalAccessException {
            super();
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.instance = clazz.newInstance();
        }

        private final Class<?> clazz;

        Builder<T> setProperty(String name, Object value)
                throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException,
                InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException,
                SecurityException {

            Method method = clazz.getMethod("set"
                    + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1),
                    value.getClass());
            method.invoke(instance, value);
            return this;
        }

        T create() {
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

how to use it:
yo are creating instance of builder by passing class to constructor

`Builder<MyClass> builder = new Builder<>(MyClass.class);`

and then use method `setProperty(String name, Object value)` to call setter on your object,

what you coul done? for example pass some default values for your class and dont use non-args constructor

Comment: I created a version of this that uses the Builder Pattern:

Comment: [Here is the code] (http://derrickbowen.com/blog/content/generic-builder-pattern-class-using-generics-reflection)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this is what you wanted, however if I were you I will implement like below//

main >>

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericBuilder gb = GenericBuilder.getInstance();
        gb=
        gb.withThisProperty("String", "AAAAAA").
        withThisProperty(4, 9).
        withThisProperty(5.8f, 6.7f).
        withThisProperty("Array", new ArrayList<String>()).build();

        System.out.println(gb.toString());
    }
};
```

VO >>

```
public class GenericBuilder {

    private Map<Object, Object> map;

    // Implementation of Singleton 
    private GenericBuilder (){
        map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }

    private static class LazyLoader{
        private static final GenericBuilder INSTANCE = new GenericBuilder(); 
    }

    public static GenericBuilder getInstance(){
        return LazyLoader.INSTANCE;
    }
    //End Singleton

    public GenericBuilder withThisProperty(Object key, Object param){
        map.put(key, param);
        return this;
    }

    public Object get(Object key){
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public GenericBuilder build(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer returnVal = new StringBuffer();
        Iterator<Object> iter = map.keySet().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Object key = iter.next();
            returnVal.append("key >> " + key  + " value >> " + map.get(key) + "\n");
        }
        return returnVal.toString();
    }
}
```

I overriden toString() to show what is in it, and declare a Map to assign value to somewhere, if you want you can change this with other Collections. Thanks/