# How to build abstract classes using builder pattern?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

This the abstract class I have

```
public abstract class AbstractActionModel implements IActionModel{
    public abstract void getModel();
    public abstract void getAction();
}
```

Then I want to use this abstract class like below :

```
this.getActions().put("sth", AbstractActionModel.builder().action("sth").build());
```

Since I can not instantiate an abstract class the builder pattern wont work.I don't know any alternative patterns for doing this either.

Note: Also I have no knowledge of classes extended from this base class.

Comment: How do you want to choose which of the concrete subclasses to create?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909701/generic-builder-pattern-class-using-reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a builder without knowledge of the concrete subclasses, the caller of your code will have to supply information about which subclass to create - either by providing an actual class object, or registering a set of classes with names. For example:

```
public class Builders
{

    public static abstract class AbstractActionModel
    {
        public abstract void getModel();

        public abstract void getAction();
        public abstract void setAction(String action);
    }

    public static class ConcreteActionModel extends AbstractActionModel
    {
        public void getModel() {};

        public void getAction() {};
        public void setAction(String action) {};
    }

    public static class ModelBuilder
    {
        AbstractActionModel model;

        Map<String, Class<? extends AbstractActionModel>> register = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends AbstractActionModel>>();
        public void register(String key, Class<? extends AbstractActionModel> c) {register.put("concrete", ConcreteActionModel.class);}

        public ModelBuilder choose(String key) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {          
            model = register.get(key).newInstance();
            return this;
        }

        public ModelBuilder action(String action) {
            model.setAction(action);
            return this;
        }

        public AbstractActionModel build() {
            return model;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {       
        ModelBuilder mb = new ModelBuilder();
        mb.register("concrete", ConcreteActionModel.class);
        mb.choose("concrete").action("sth").build();
    }
}
```

Note that the abstract class will need setter methods adding, so that the builder can update properties without knowing the concrete subclass.

Alternatively, you could use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909701/generic-builder-pattern-class-using-reflection) to inspect the subclass and call its methods.

Comment: So there is no static way of doing this? like this AbstractActionModel.builder() ?

Comment: Not without supplying a concrete class or a way to get one - how can you build something if you don't know what it is?